# Unable to type in Text box field using sendKeys method. The xpath is working fine, since when i tried to click on textbox it works

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, textbox, sendkeys

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement External = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@id ='External_Reviewer']"));
        External.click();
        External.sendKeys("kevin");
```

The textbox is an autosuggestion with a people picker field. Is there any other way than using only "sendKeys" method. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript executor

```
External =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@id ='External_Reviewer']"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"yourvalue"')", External);
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium executes so fast. You just need to add some wait after click is performed and then use sendKeys().

So, it will be like:

```
External.click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
External.sendKeys("kevin");
```

Answer (score 0):

if `sendKeys()` not working, you can try with `Actions`class. Please try with below function:

```
public void typeTextIntoSpecialInput(WebElement elem, String input) {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    this.moveToElement(elem, true);
    actions.sendKeys(input);
    actions.build().perform();
}
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue, and clicking on the text box before sending keys worked for me